# How to select one column from datagrid and add data for the selected column from field text?

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I want to select column from data grid view.
Then, I want to add data in cells number 5 for the selected column.

Below code is not worked.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvSRP.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    dgvSRP.Rows.Add();
    DataGridViewRow row = this.dgvSRP.Rows[i];
    row.Cells[5].Value =txtJumlahPEsanan.Text;
}
```

Comment: In this code you are selection rows. How you want to select columns?

Comment: dnt understand could you please explain what you exactly want..

Comment: sorry for wrong words.

Comment: I mean how to select row..

Comment: Why are you adding a row inside your loop? Remove `dgvSRP.Rows.Add();`

Comment: You mean how to get selected row, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var dgvRow in dgvSRP.Rows)
{
    dgvRow.Cells[4].Value = txtJumlahPEsanan.Text; // The 5th column is index 4. Indexes always start at 0.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code i have select specific column value and assign it to textbox. May this solve your problem. Remember i have two cells rows thats why i kept cell[1] because index start from 0.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 5)
            {
                textBox3.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
```